# Java Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, text

Hallo,

I have the following syntax:

```
@AAAA{tralala10aa,
  author = {Some Author},
  title = {Some Title},
  booktitle = {Some Booktitle},
  year = {2010},
  month = {March},
  booktitle_short = {CC 2010},
  conference_url = {http://www.mmmm.com},
  projects = {projects}
}
```

....

I've made the following regular expression:

```
@[A-Z]*[{][a-z0-9]*[,]
```

but I need the whole text block. How can I do it ?

Comment: Define "the whole text block"

Comment: Indenting your code by four spaces is the correct way to format it.

Comment: I have many text blocks like this: 
@AAAA{tralala10aa,
  author = {Some Author},
  title = {Some Title},
  booktitle = {Some Booktitle},
  year = {2010},
  month = {March},
  booktitle_short = {CC 2010},
  conference_url = {http://www.mmmm.com},
  projects = {projects}
}

I need to separate them.

Comment: Can a comma occur in-between? I personally would not use a regex here.

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve. You've given some input data, but haven't said what you are attempting to do. Are you attempting to match all of the text between the `@AAAA{` and `}`?

Comment: @Brian Campbell : yes i want to match all text between @AA{ and }

Comment: @aphex - this is an example, not a syntax.  If you want a decent answer (i.e. one that won't break when you get unexpected input) you need to supply the **real** syntax.  In particular: 1) is it "legal" to have a '{' or '}' character within the inner '{...}' pairs?  2) how many of these things are present in the input stream / file you are "parsing" with the regex?

Comment: @aphex: My expr had a typo, which I've corrected. Please try again and let me know what happens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "block" always ends with a lone closing brace, then this <s>may</s>will do it:

```
"(?ms)@[A-Z]+\\{.+?^\\}$"
```

Where `(?ms)` sets the expression to "multiline" and "dotall" (so the `.+` can also match newlines), and the stuff at the end matches a closing brace on a line by itself.

The question mark in the middle makes the `.+` match non-greedy so it won't match all blocks up to and including the last block in the file.

Comment: It doesn't work. When i have  more blocks it matches them all as one.

Comment: Oops, sorry! I just corrected a bug in my expression. Please try again!

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the feedback, I'd been chewing my nails here.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you would be much better off using a context-free grammar instead of a regular expression in this case. Consider using a parser generator, such as [CUP](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/) or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Comment: Woudn't be  easy to match all with @AAA{ some text }} ?
I don't know how to express: "some text"
and at the end }}

Comment: I think Anon's regular expression will get the text, but ONLY if nested braces are one-deep. A CFG will also make it easy to parse the individual statements inside the block.

Comment: If you want to match more than one level of nesting, you have three options: Extend the regular expression to those deeper levels (assuming a finite depth), use a recursive (and thus nonregular) expression (Perl has these, don't know about Java), or use a proper parser.

Comment: Grats on all the upvotes, but it seems I found a simple regexp that satisfies the requirements ;)

Answer (score 2):

If the nesting on braces is only allowed one-deep:

```
/@[A-Z]*{([^{}]*+|{[^{}]*+})*}/
```

Note the use of the possessive quantifier `*+` - without it, this can take quite a long time on failed matches.

I'm not sure if Java supports it - if it doesn't, remove it, but keep in mind the poor failure-behaviour.

Comment: Is there anything in this expression or answer text making this expression multiline capable?

Comment: You don't need the leading and trailing slashes, the Regex constructor in Java just takes a regular String (so there are instances where you'll have to do double escaping but not in this case). Also, it does support possessive quantifiers so you won't have a problem there.

Comment: Would `[^{}]` in a Java regex match newlines by default? If not, the singleline attribute `/s` would need to be specified.

Comment: @Anon: I don't think so. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use regex, I would tokenize the string and build up a dictionary. Sorry, this is a Python implementation (not Java):

```
>>> s ="""@AAAA{tralala10aa,
  author = {Some Author},
  title = {Some Title},
  booktitle = {Some Booktitle},
  year = {2010},
  month = {March},
  booktitle_short = {CC 2010},
  conference_url = {http://www.mmmm.com},
  projects = {projects}
}"""
>>> 
>>> s
'@AAAA{tralala10aa,\n  author = {Some Author},\n  title = {Some Title},\n  booktitle = {Some Booktitle},\n  year = {2010},\n  month = {March},\n  booktitle_short = {CC 2010},\n  conference_url = {http://www.mmmm.com},\n  projects = {projects}\n}'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> lst = s.replace('@AAA', '').replace('{', '').replace('}', '').split(',\n')
>>> lst
['Atralala10aa', '  author = Some Author', '  title = Some Title', '  booktitle = Some Booktitle', '  year = 2010', '  month = March', '  booktitle_short = CC 2010', '  conference_url = http://www.mmmm.com', '  projects = projects\n']
>>> dct = dict((x[0].strip(), x[1].strip()) for x in (y.split('=') for y in lst[1:]))
>>> dct
{'booktitle_short': 'CC 2010', 'title': 'Some Title', 'booktitle': 'Some Booktitle', 'author': 'Some Author', 'month': 'March', 'conference_url': 'http://www.mmmm.com', 'year': '2010', 'projects': 'projects'}
>>> 
>>> dct['title']
'Some Title'
>>>
```

Hopefully the code above seems self explanatory.

Comment: -1 - this doesn't answer this (clearly) Java-specific question.

Comment: Nevertheless, it is a better solution than using a regexp.

Comment: @quant_dev - if you think dictionaries are a better way to solve the problem, code the solution in Java and post it as your own answer.